# How much closed cell expanding foam insulation do I need?

Tags: insulation, spray-foam

I am considering insulating my van using closed cell expanding foam cans.

The product I like the look of and reviews is Soudafoam B2 Gun Grade 750ml Can.

Is 50mm all round, good enough to keep me warm in the winter in the UK? Could I get away with less or do I need more?

Comment: Are we talking #vanlife here?  We don't really do motor vehicles on this stack otherwise.  Did you know England and Wales have a vast narrowboat community, and it has become a refuge for limited-means folks, many of whom live on their boats all year? They have the same problem, insulating against English winters without the insulation taking too much of their living space. They would know all the best stuff.

Comment: It's a generic DIY question... How much does one can cover? No one seems to conclusively know. And yes the van is my home - well going to be... And I am in England... And I have lived in a foam insulated boat for years... That was done by a contractor, not DIY cans.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the product's [data sheet](http://www.sealfix.co.uk/WebRoot/BT4/Shops/BT4207/MediaGallery/Datasheets/Soudafoam_Gun_B2_13102014.pdf) a 750ml can yields 43l.

I'm getting 0.86 square meters per can at 50mm thickness but I don't do stuff with the metric system often so I suggest you double-check my numbers based on the data sheet and see if we agree.

As to if it will keep you warm or not, that all depends on your heat source.

Comment: Thank you for replying. How did you get to that result? What formula did you use?

Comment: @LeonardoSeccia Well, 1 L = 1,000 cubic centimeters so your can is 43,000 cc. You want 50 mm or 5 cm thickness, so you need 5 square cm per cm of surface area. 43,000 CC / 5 SQ Cm = 8600 Cm Sq of surface you can cover at 5 cm thick. 1 square meter is 100 x 100 cm, or 10,000 square centimeters, so 8600 cm sq / 10000 cm sq gives .86 square meters.